Children cartoon about a boy who lives with his father
I watched this cartoon as a kid when I lived in France, so the years are between 1985 and 1989.
The cartoon was drawn with pastel colors and simple clear lines, the faces of the characters were circles or squares with rounded corners.
It was about a young boy who lives with his father. The mother is never seen and it's never really explained why she isn't here.
The dad was always serene, and a positive figure.
The episodes were very short. I was probably European, maybe Danish or Swedish.
I thought that the name for this cartoon was "Alphonse" for a long time, but I can't find anything about that.
The style was somehow similar to Robin by Magnus Carlsson, but more for kids (and it isn't from him, I checked his other works).

It sounds like Alfons Aberg (AKA Alfie Atkins), a Swedish series of children's books from the 70s that was also a TV series. Alfons lived with his kind father and it was all in crude drawings. Here's a clip:




Oh my god yes! This is it! Thank you so much for helping me rediscover one of my oldest TV childhood memories.

No problem. I actually knew the books, so it was a nice trip down memory lane for me too. ;)

Are you Swedish? That's another question in itself, but I always wondered if Magnus Carlsson's Robin looking like a grown-up Alfons was meant or just coincidence...

It could've been influenced by it, I guess. Are you Swedish The books were sold internationally. ;)

Oh! I didn't know that! Thanks for the added info!
